# How to find if checkboxes in table cells are checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, html-table

In Jquery, I have a table where each column can have multiple checkboxes. I want to know if at least one checkbox is checked in a particular column. For example

```
<TABLE id="dataTable">
    <TR>
        <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" id="chkId1" class="chk"/></TD> 
        <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" id="chkId12" class="chk"/></TD> 
        <TD><INPUT type="text" value="data1"/></TD> 
        <TD><INPUT type="text" value="data2"/></TD>
    <TR>
        <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" id="chkId2" class="chk"/></TD>
        <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" id="chkId22" class="chk"/></TD>
        <TD><INPUT type="text" value="data3"/></TD> 
        <TD><INPUT type="text" value="data4"/></TD> 
</TABLE>
```

I have two rows here and four columns. I need to see if column1 or column2 have any checked checkboxes.

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: `$("#dataTable tr td").first().find("input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked")`

Comment: Did you attempt to find this? It's pretty easy to find, not to mention when you type the question title in the duplicate appears as a possible duplicate...!

Answer (score 0):

A simple example:

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function(){
  console.log('ID:[' + this.id + '] is checked? ' + $(this).prop("checked"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<TABLE id="dataTable">
    <TR>
        <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" id="chkId1" class="chk"/></TD> 
        <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" id="chkId12" class="chk"/></TD> 
        <TD><INPUT type="text" value="data1"/></TD> 
        <TD><INPUT type="text" value="data2"/></TD>
    <TR>
        <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" id="chkId2" class="chk"/></TD>
        <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" id="chkId22" class="chk"/></TD>
        <TD><INPUT type="text" value="data3"/></TD> 
        <TD><INPUT type="text" value="data4"/></TD> 
</TABLE>
```